# cb mode of transistor for amplification

Tags: transistors

Why is there no current gain but voltage gain in common base mode of transistor? And what difference between common base mode and common emitter mode cause amplification in ce but not in cb mode?

Comment: Look here: https://people.seas.harvard.edu/~jones/es154/lectures/lecture_3/bjt_amps/bjt_amps.html for a proper explanation of all BJT configurations

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Ib = Ic/beta, hence the difference of emitter and collector current is very small. That is where your current gain of slightly less then unity comes from. In common emitter mode, there is a significant difference between base and collector current, so there is substantial current amplification.

The input impedance of the common base configuration is very low, therefore a low voltage exists at the input, the output voltage depends on the collector resistor. When this resistance is sufficiently large, there is voltage amplification.

Comment: why is there significant difference between base and collector current in common emitter mode? but why not in common base mode?

Comment: There is a significnt difference between Ic and Ib in cb mode (a factor of beta), but in cb mode, we're not interested in Ib, Ie is the input current

Comment: In both modes the difference is significant. Because Ic = beta*Ib, and Ie = Ib + Ic, for large beta, the difference between Ie and Ic is small. Beta is a transistor parameter, and does not depend on the configuration.

Comment: the input is electron for both confoguration from negative side of a source. and in both configuration the negative side is connected to emitter. how can the input be different?

Comment: can the input in base considered as negative? (the actual input is electron through emitter and very few electrons pass out through base giving rise to base current directed out of base. so considerimg -ve for changing direction of base current(despite being scaler),for understanding only)